# How to run async Twisted reactor and asyncio loops infinitely

Tags: python, python-asyncio, twisted

I have two libraries, both of which provide listener functions (which run on different ports) and listen for network activity. (My program provides a interface layer between them.)

The issue is that one uses Twisted:

```py
from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.run()
```

And the other uses asyncio

```py
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(...)
loop.run_forever()
```

Both of these calls seem to block the main thread: if I put one before the other, neither runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with Twisted's [`AsyncioSelectorReactor`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor.html). Instead of letting Twisted creating its own Reactor loop, you can tell it to use the main asyncio event loop.

```py
import asyncio

from twisted.internet import asyncioreactor
asyncioreactor.install(asyncio.get_event_loop())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(...)

reactor = asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor()
reactor.run()
```

You only have to call `run` on the `reactor`, that will call `run_forever`.

Comment: You don't instantiate a reactor after installing it.  Instead, you just import `twisted.internet.reactor` *after* installing the desired reactor.